# How to see which files are included in a webpack build

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Is there a way to see which files are included in a webpack build and preferably, their size? 
The reason I want this is to gain insight into my builds and also keep an eye out for accidental inclusion of files that should not be in there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, the webpack CLI will print the path of all included modules and their respective size.

Webpack can also generate a `stats.json` file for you, which contains information about every module included in your build.

From the CLI:

```
webpack --json > stats.json
```

From the NodeJS API:

```js
webpack(config, function(err, stats) {
  fs.writeFileSync('./stats.json', JSON.stringify(stats.toJson()));
});
```

You can then either write your own stats analyser tool, or use already existing tools like the excellent [webpack stats analyser](http://webpack.github.io/analyse/).

Comment: I do 'webpack --json > stats.json' but stats.json is empty. What do I do wrong?

Comment: @WebBrother and anyone else reaching this page via search, this answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41520410/