# Webpack stats.json file is empty

Tags: webpack

When I run the following command I get an empty stats.json file:

```
webpack --env production --profile --json --output-filename stats.json
```

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html Says *`--json` Write JSON to stdout instead of a human readable format.* What happens if you pipe stdout to `stats.json`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I discovered that as I was using different Webpack config files for dev and production environmnets, I needed to include the `--config` option in the command:

```
webpack --env production --profile --json --config='webpack.config.prod.js' --output-filename='stats.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

Was having issues with a windows 10 machine. How it worked for me:

On command line (powershell was not working) go to the folder with the package.json and set the environment to production:

> $ set NODE_ENV=production

Run webpack with no single quotes and without an output file, just redirect the output to stats.json:

> $ webpack --profile --json --config=config\webpack.config.prod.js > stats.json

After this, you should have a stats.json that should show you some info at http://webpack.github.io/analyse/